# Reading an integer file to an integer list in sml

Tags: io, sml, smlnj

Hi i won't to make a function in standard ML that takes as input integers separated by spaces in many lines and returns a list of them one by one.
For example, for the input file

```
3 4 5 6 7 8 4
4 5 6 2 3 
6 4 3 2
2 3 5 6 7
```

to return a list `[3,4,5,6,7,8,4,4,5,6,2,3,6,4,3,2,2,3,5,6,7]`.

I had tried to figure it out myself but i couldn't because i don't have good knowledge of ML's IO functions.
I would appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Sebastian.
here is an example reading integer

```
fun int_from_stream stream =
  Option.valOf (TextIO.scanStream (Int.scan StringCvt.DEC) stream)

val fstream = TextIO.openIn file
val N = int_from_stream fstream
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`TextIO.scanStream`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/text-io.html#SIG:TEXT_IO.scanStream:VAL) and [`Int.scan`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/integer.html#SIG:INTEGER.scan:VAL). This will produce an `int option`, which contains the next integer in the file if one is available.

You can then simply build up a list of all the integers in the file, by calling this function repeatedly until you get a `NONE`, signifying that there are no more integers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
  fun readint(infile : string) = let

        val ins = TextIO.openIn infile


    fun loop ins =

        case TextIO.scanStream( Int.scan StringCvt.DEC) ins of

    SOME int => int :: loop ins

    | NONE => []

          in
 loop ins before TextIO.closeIn ins

  end;
```